# Should I be subscribing to events inside my controller and calling apply to update the view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building an Angular App that inside my `parentController`, I setup a `DataTable`. When rows are clicked in the table, I need some buttons to enable/disable which I was planning on doing by subscribing to events that the DataTable API provides:

```
app.controller('parentController', function($stateParams, $scope, $rootScope, $state) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.test = {};
  vm.test.val = 'hello';
}

app.controller('childController', function($stateParams, $scope, $rootScope, $state) {
    var vm = this;

    var table = $('#data-table').DataTable({});

    table.on('select', function(e, dt, node, config) {
        vm.test.val = 'selected!';
    }

    table.on('deselect', function(e, dt, node, config) {
    }
}
```

Unfortunately though, `{{ vm.test.val }}` doesn't update on the view without calling `$scope.$apply();`.

To me, calling the `$apply` method seems to be a red flag that the design of this is not correct. What is the best way to handle this so that I can apply changes to the view that are changed from within an event callback?

Comment: register DOM event from the controller is not good practice, basically controller shouldn't have any operation regarding DOM directly. Why don't you use `ng-click` directive that will be there on each row,(it obivious that row are getting selected by clicking them), then just you could fire one function, which will have logic to get selected and deselected row.

Comment: The problem here is that you are using `query` , you have to organize tabbing through `angluarjs`

Comment: @Pankaj Parkar- I'll go down the route of using ng-click. Where would the function that determines what row was clicked live? Would it be inside the controller?

Comment: @Armen I'm not sure what you mean. Haven't mentioned anything about tabbing or query.

Comment: but seems in your code jquery selector is present `$('#data-table').DataTable({});`, and you are setting `table.on('select'` and `table.on('deselect'` events listeners on it, isn't this all jquery ?

Comment: @Armen. You mean JQuery. Yes I am selecting the tables to apply the `DataTable` to.. however I still don't understand what your comment is suggesting is wrong with selecting the elements through JQuery. What do you suggest?

Comment: Yes sorry i did not so that i'm missing `j` there, so my suggestion is to not use external lib(like `jquery`) to build tabbing you can easily build it based on only angluarjs and you will not have problems with `$apply` Example: - http://codepen.io/jasoncluck/pen/iDcbh

Comment: @Armen. I see.. however I am not talking about tabbing. I am talking about a table.

Comment: I dont know any other way than `$apply` when I need to update a `$scope` variable from within a dataTables event, even when using angular dataTables. It does not seem to be possible.  Not necessarily because it is not correct design but because we _are_ in fact dealing with jQuery dataTables.